# Выполнить строку как исполняемый код в C#

Tags: c#

Есть строковые конструкции заранее неизвестно какие, но они могут быть любой сложности и длины следующего вида:
('abc' == 'abc' || 'xyz' == 'zyx') || ('abc' == 'dfg' && 'xyz' == 'zyx')
Разнообразие сравнений данных и их количество (как и количество вложенных скобок) заранее не может быть известно, поэтому парсер на разбор вложенных скобок и математическое упрощение для меня совсем муторно и на очень долго затянется. Поэтому хочу узнать возможно ли все таки такую строку передать компилятору в виде кода и получить результат ее исполнения.

Comment: Парсер пишется быстро...

Comment: лучше не исполнять код из каких-то строк. сделай xml в которой будешь описывать свою структуру

Comment: dgzargo, каким образом?

Answer (score 0):

лучше не исполнять код из каких-то строк - можно подменить код и твое приложение его исполнит
сделай xml в которой будешь описывать свою структуру
например:

```
<or>
    <or>
        <equal>
            <string value="abc"/>
            <string value="abc"/>
        </equal>
        <equal>
            <string value="xyz"/>
            <string value="zyx"/>
        </equal>
    </or>
    <and>
        <equal>
            <string value="abc"/>
            <string value="dfg"/>
        </equal>
        <equal>
            <string value="xyz"/>
            <string value="zyx"/>
        </equal>
    </and>
</or>
```

для чего-то вроде этого намного легче написать обработчик и инъекции не допускает
нужно не забыть это:

- операции сравнения возвращают тип bool
- внутри операций сравнения должно быть ДВА ОДИНАКОВЫХ по типу значения
- предусмотреть нужные типы данных и их парсинг из строки value

любое из нарушений - несоответствие формату (помимо банального нарушения формата xml)